# Couldn't pass value to textbox for more than one time without refreshing the page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

When i pass a value to textbox using Javascript it is working fine for the first time before updating data, after the update table will be refreshed. Then I couldn't pass value to textbox in the same way, but its working if I refresh the browser.

```
<div id="div_for_values"><a href="#" key_id="<?php echo $name_id; ?>" key_value="<?php echo $name; ?>">Edit</a></div>

$(function(){
    $("#div_for_values  a").click(function(){
        var key_id = $(this).attr("key_id");
        var key_value = $(this).attr("key_value");
       $('#txt_name_id').val(key_id);
       $('#txt_name').val(key_value);
       return false;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This line only parsed before page load.

```
<div id="div_for_values"><a href="#" key_id="<?php echo $name_id; ?>" key_value="<?php echo $name; ?>">Edit</a></div>
```

The browser will only see this:

```
<div id="div_for_values"><a href="#" key_id="value1" key_value="value2">Edit</a></div>
```

You might want to use some ajax calls to insert fresh data into your fields.